# Local DNS dissapears from resolver after a while

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, netplan

Ubuntu 18.04 desktop upgraded from 16.04.
I have a strange problem that I can't solve.

After upgrading, I continued doing the network config as I always have (interfaces, resolv, ...) before I noticed the switch to netplan. Now I'm trying to be good and change it but I must have messed something up.

After a reboot or "systemctl restart systemd-networkd" everything is fine. nslookup works for both WAN and LAN. But after a while, LAN lookup stops working and as far as I can see, nothing has changed.

diskstation (192.168.0.42) is my NAS which is the local DNS.

After restart:

```
nslookup diskstation.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   diskstation.lan
Address: 192.168.0.42
```

A while later (without me doing anything):

```
nslookup diskstation.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find diskstation.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

But this works:

```
nslookup diskstation.lan 192.168.0.42
Server:     192.168.0.42
Address:    192.168.0.42#53

Name:   diskstation.lan
Address: 192.168.0.42
```

My netplan file 01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp33s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.46/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          search: [lan]
          addresses: [192.168.0.42, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Resolve status:

```
systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNS Domain: lan
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp33s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.42
                      8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
          DNS Domain: lan
```

The strange thing is that nothing have changed when it stops working.
I did a `find / -mmin -60` and no changes.
Status output (from resolve for example) doesn't change either.

```
ifconfig
enp33s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.46  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::329c:23ff:fe00:5fd8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:9c:23:00:5f:d8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2925377  bytes 3969527143 (3.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1245146  bytes 143284968 (143.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 218578  bytes 19744358 (19.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 218578  bytes 19744358 (19.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here it is:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-=============================================================================
un  dnsmasq                              <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base                         2.79-1                  amd64                   Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
un  dnsmasq-base-lua                     <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have listed both a private nameserver and public nameservers in your config, and these do not have the same view of DNS.  Since you have a stateful local resolver (resolved), if your first DNS server is temporarily unavailable for any reason (simply meaning that it didn't answer in time), resolution falls back to the next server in the list, which is a public name server which doesn't know about your local names.

To avoid this, you should use only private nameservers in your config without a public fallback.