# How to edit DNSname in 20.04 so I can us my local DNS?

Tags: network-manager, dns

I have a two local DNS configured which sometimes works and sometimes it does not, using Ubuntu 20.04

I defined my local DNS with the GUI:
[image]

Why it works sometimes and sometime not is very well explained in [Local DNS dissapears from resolver after a while](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215963/local-dns-dissapears-from-resolver-after-a-while) . The internet is slow, there is a timeout and access to the public DNS fails. So then next DNSnames server appears, which is my local DNS. And than I can access my local URL.

When executing `systemd-resolve --status | sed -n '/DNS Servers/,/^$/p'` I get:

```
DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3    
                      192.168.1.70
                      192.168.1.1 
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

But DNS server 10.0.2.3 I never defined, as far as I can recall.

When, again sometimes, my local DNS is used, everything works as desired. I can check this with:

```
resolvectl status
```

if it returns (I stripped the content a bit):

```
Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS         
DefaultRoute setting: yes         
       LLMNR setting: yes         
MulticastDNS setting: no          
  DNSOverTLS setting: no          
      DNSSEC setting: no          
    DNSSEC supported: no          
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.70
         DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3    
                      192.168.1.70
                      192.168.1.1 
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

So the current DNS Server: 192.168.1.70 as wanted. But this is not always the case. I want to make my system more stable it will always use 192.168.1.70

When `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` I can see 10.0.2.3 is really defined. I can not (and should not) edit this file but edit  /etc/resolv.conf instead.

Viewing `cat /etc/resolv.conf` does not show DNS server 10.0.2.3 but is does show `nameserver 127.0.0.53` And, it again I should not edit this file.

This is weird. First, from a generated file, I get pointed to a file which is used to generated that file and which I should edit instead. And second in that file is a different DNS nameserver mentioned so it seems `run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` is generated from somewhere else.

According to https://askubuntu.com/tags/resolvconf/info is the program to edit resolv.conf. So I tried to use that.

```
bernard@VBoxMain20:/etc$ resolvconf

Command 'resolvconf' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openresolv  # version 3.10.0-1, or
sudo apt install resolvconf  # version 1.82

bernard@VBoxMain20:/etc$ sudo apt install openresolv
```

So I executed `resolvconf` but found no way to edit resolv.conf

I also tried to use netplan available from Ubuntu 18.04+ but without success.

I simply want to use the DNS nameservers I defined myself in the GUI and nothing else. How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't 10.0.2.3 coming from your DHCP? You get DNS addresses from DHCP and then  your 192.* are added to the list

Comment: Possible. In the GUI I wanted to disable DHCP, but I could not. For two days it has the same value. I do not know how fast the IP addresses do change with DHCP.

Comment: In other words, you probably need to use manual option in that dialog. I use Ubuntu Mate and there are two options for that - "Automatic (DHCP)" and "Automatic (DHCP) address only". I use the second one and only DNS I specify there is used.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I unfortunately I do not have that option.

Comment: I use this if I need to specify DNS. Of course it will be overwritten when you connect next time
`sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=10.88.17.67 -i enp0s31f6 `

Comment: and also different DNS for different domain
`sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=10.88.17.1 -i mpqemubr0 --set-domain=multipass`

Comment: I would like a stable solution. I work with the internal DNS on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question: is this VirtualBox instance using a NAT network? If so, you have two options:

1. Switch to a "Bridged Network", which will result in the VM having full control over its network resources
2. Use the host's resolver as a DNS Proxy. As per [the documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns):

> For resolving network names, the DHCP server of the NAT engine offers a list of registered DNS servers of the host. If for some reason you need to hide this DNS server list and use the host's resolver settings, thereby forcing the VirtualBox NAT engine to intercept DNS requests and forward them to host's resolver, use the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

> Note that this setting is similar to the DNS proxy mode, however whereas the proxy mode just forwards DNS requests to the appropriate servers, the resolver mode will interpret the DNS requests and use the host's DNS API to query the information and return it to the guest.

I generally run all my VBox instances in bridges mode as it avoids these sorts of issues.

Hope this gives you what you need

Comment: I used your suggestion 1, using "Bridged Network". I really like simple, to the point solution, you gave me. Thanks you very much.